# Return a list of links from a webpage in R

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a function in r that, given an address, will return a list of links on that webpage.

For example:

```
getLinks("http://prog21.dadgum.com/109.html")
```

Would return:

```
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/prog21.css"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/atom.xml"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/index.html"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/archives.html"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/atom.xml"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/56.html"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/39.html"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/109.html"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/108.html"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/107.html"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/106.html"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/105.html"
"http://prog21.dadgum.com/104.html"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function seems to work on other webpages, but for some reason does not return the complete URLs for the page in question.  I'm interested to see if there's a better way to do this.

```
getLinks <- function(URL) {
    require(XML)
    doc <- htmlParse(URL)
    out <- unlist(doc['//@href'])
    names(out) <- NULL
    out
}
```